# SQL Server packing multiple bit fields in a table

Tags: sql-server, bit, ddl

I'm using SQL Server 2016, but I think the question should apply to all versions of SQL Server ...

I understand that if you have multiple bit fields in a table that the fields are packed together to save space. Will SQL Server pack the bit fields even if they don't appear contiguously, like this?:-

```
create table test (
    field1 int,
    field2 bit,
    field3 varchar(100),
    field4 bit,
    field5 varchar(100),
    field6 bit
)
```

Or do I need to put all the bit fields together, like this:-

```
create table test (
    field1 int,
    field3 varchar(100),
    field5 varchar(100),
    field2 bit,
    field4 bit,
    field6 bit
)
```

Comment: By "packed together" I assume you mean how the data is stored behind the scenes.  SQL Server stores data in 8K pages.  If it can fit all the data in a page it will, otherwise the data will be spread across multiple pages.  Your schema definition doesn't do anything to affect that.

Comment: Microsoft's documentation says "The SQL Server Database Engine optimizes storage of bit columns. If there are 8 or fewer bit columns in a table, the columns are stored as 1 byte.". But do the bit fields need to be adjacent in the table? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/bit-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Yes.  But my point really is that SQL Server does that in the background.  Your DDL doesn't affect it.  It doesn't matter in which order your fields are defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR; SQL Server will pack bit fields no matter the order of their definition.

If we were to run the following

```
create table test_dispersed (
    field1 int,
    field2 bit,
    field3 varchar(100),
    field4 bit,
    field5 varchar(100),
    field6 bit
)

create table test_contiguous (
    field1 int,
    field3 varchar(100),
    field5 varchar(100),
    field2 bit,
    field4 bit,
    field6 bit
)

insert into test_dispersed (field1, field2, field3, field4, field5, field6) values (123,0,'A string',1,'Another string',0);
insert into test_contiguous (field1, field2, field3, field4, field5, field6) values (123,0,'A string',1,'Another string',0);


SELECT * FROM sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats (DB_ID(N'YourDbName'), OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[test_dispersed]'), NULL, NULL , 'DETAILED')
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats (DB_ID(N'YourDbName'), OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[test_contiguous]'), NULL, NULL , 'DETAILED')
```

You will see for both tables the `[max_record_size_in_bytes, min_record_size_in_bytes, avg_record_size_in_bytes]` are all the same and equal across tables at 54 bytes.